# Bizarre HTML Behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have encountered a bizarre problem when attempting to develop the login screen for my Intranet database.  When I try logging in with a correct pairing of User Name and Password it fails unless I add or remove some (seemingly unrelated) lines of HTML from the page's code and / or change the indenting of a line within the page's code and / or move an element's tags to or from the same line.  I have been unable to discern either rhyme or reason as to which modifications need to be made.

I have included the following code to illustrate the problem.  Please Note : I have tried reducing this code in the interests of minimalism, but if I reduce it any further then the problem does not occur.

HTML / PHP (Index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    require "ConnDB.php";
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "initial-scale = 1.0, width = device-width">

        <link href = "CSS/Intranet%20Project.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id     = "entire-page"
              action = "Index.php"
              method = "post"
        >
            User Name

            <input id    = "user-name-entry"
                   class = "border-01px-black-solid"
                   name  = "user-name-value"
                   type  = "text"
            >

            Password

            <input id    = "password-entry"
                   class = "border-01px-black-solid"
                   name  = "password-value"
                   type  = "password"
            >

            <input id    = "login-button"
                   name  = "login-submit"
                   type  = "submit"
                   value = "Log In"
            >

            <div id = "footer-section">
                <div id = "footer-internal-links">
                    <div id    = "footer-internal-links-box"
                         class = "vertically-centred"
                    >
                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-site-map-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Site Map
                        </span>

                        <div id    = "footer-internal-links-buffer-1"
                             class = "footer-internal-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-privacy-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Privacy
                        </span>

                        <div id    = "footer-internal-links-buffer-2"
                             class = "footer-internal-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-disclaimer-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Disclaimer
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id = "footer-external-links">
                    <div id    = "footer-external-links-box"
                         class = "vertically-centred"
                    >
                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-facebook"
                             alt   = "External Link Facebook"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >

                        <div id    = "footer-external-links-buffer-1"
                             class = "footer-external-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-twitter"
                             alt   = "External Link Twitter"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >

                        <div id    = "footer-external-links-buffer-2"
                             class = "footer-external-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-youtube"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
            if ( isset( $_POST[ 'login-submit' ] ) )
            {
                $userName = trim( $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] );
                $password = trim( $_POST[ 'password-value' ] );

                $intranetDatabaseConnection = $dbConnection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE fldUserName = ? AND BINARY fldPassword = ?;" );

                if ( $intranetDatabaseConnection === false )
                {
                    echo '<script>alert( "Invalid Database connection" )</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->bindParam( 1, $userName );
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->bindParam( 2, $password );
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->execute();

                    if ( $intranetDatabaseConnection->rowCount() == 0 )
                    {
                        echo '<script>alert("An invalid combination of User Name and Password was entered.")</script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION[ "InternalSummons" ] = true;

                        foreach ( $intranetDatabaseConnection as $intranetDatabaseRow )
                        {
                            if ( $intranetDatabaseRow['fldLevel'] == 1 )
                            {
                                $_SESSION[ "UserLevel" ] = "Administrator";

                                $host = $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ];
                                $uri  = rtrim( dirname( $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] ),
                                               '/\\' );

                                $extra = "User%20Administration.php";

                                header( "Location: http://$host$uri/$extra" );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $_SESSION[ 'UserLevel' ] = "Invalid";

                                echo "<script>alert( \"An invalid User Access Level has been detected for that User.\" )</script>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML / PHP (ConnDB.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    try
    {
        $dbConnection = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=intranet_project; charset=utf8",
                                 "root",
                                 "Password1" );
    }
    catch ( PDOException $exception )
    {
        echo "Failure : " . $exception->getMessage();
        $dbConnection->rollBack();
    }

    $_SESSION[ "seed" ] = SHA1( "IllBeThereForYou" );

    $dbConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,
                                 false );

    date_default_timezone_set( "Australia/Perth" );
?>
```

CSS (Intranet Project.css)

```
html,
*
{
    border      : 0;
    box-sizing  : border-box;
    margin      : 0;
    padding     : 0;
}

.border-01px-black-solid
{
    border       : 1px;
    border-color : black;
    border-style : solid;
}

#footer-section
{
    background-color : cyan;
}
```

MySQL Sample Database Script

```
CREATE DATABASE Intranet_Project;

USE Intranet_Project;

CREATE TABLE tblAccount
(
    fldID         MEDIUMINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fldUserName   VARCHAR( 20 )   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    fldPassword   VARCHAR( 20 )   NOT NULL,
    fldLevel      TINYINT( 1 )    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (fldID)
);

INSERT INTO tblAccount
SET fldUserName = "Sample User 001",
    fldPassword = "Password1",
    fldLevel    = 1;
```

In this case the code as presented appears to accept the login values, but simply blanks the form and does not proceed onto the User Administration page.  It does proceed if I simply remove the following line from Index.php...

```
                            Site Map
```

I have no idea why such a simple change should have such an effect.  I have spent the past few days editing the original files to identify where this problem occurs, but it seems to occur all over the place - the quoted example is merely the simplest illustration of the problem I have been able to achieve.

I have also spent much of the past few days researching the problem, but none of the many search criteria I have tried have provided anything that proved remotely useful.

My question is : Why does removing `Site Map` as mentioned above fix the problem and what caused the problem in the first place?

Please Note : This code has been tested on different versions of Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer, and the problem has remained consistent across brosers.

Comment: Aren't you getting the "headers already sent" warning/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution you should not write output before **header()**, because you have output html and then changing the location, it won't work.

```
 header( "Location: http://$host$uri/$extra" );
```

RE-EDITED

```
<?php

  require "ConnDB.php";
  $message="";
            if ( isset( $_POST[ 'login-submit' ] ) )
            {
                $userName = trim( $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] );
                $password = trim( $_POST[ 'password-value' ] );

                $intranetDatabaseConnection = $dbConnection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE fldUserName = ? AND BINARY fldPassword = ?;" );

                if ( $intranetDatabaseConnection === false )
                {
                    $message= '<script>alert( "Invalid Database connection" )</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->bindParam( 1, $userName );
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->bindParam( 2, $password );
                    $intranetDatabaseConnection->execute();

                    if ( $intranetDatabaseConnection->rowCount() == 0 )
                    {
                        $message= '<script>alert("An invalid combination of User Name and Password was entered.")</script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION[ "InternalSummons" ] = true;

                        foreach ( $intranetDatabaseConnection as $intranetDatabaseRow )
                        {
                            if ( $intranetDatabaseRow['fldLevel'] == 1 )
                            {
                                $_SESSION[ "UserLevel" ] = "Administrator";

                                $host = $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ];
                                $uri  = rtrim( dirname( $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] ),
                                               '/\\' );

                                $extra = "User%20Administration.php";

                                header( "Location: http://$host$uri/$extra" );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $_SESSION[ 'UserLevel' ] = "Invalid";

                                $message= "<script>alert( \"An invalid User Access Level has been detected for that User.\" )</script>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "initial-scale = 1.0, width = device-width">

        <link href = "CSS/Intranet%20Project.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id     = "entire-page"
              action = "Index.php"
              method = "post"
        >
            User Name

            <input id    = "user-name-entry"
                   class = "border-01px-black-solid"
                   name  = "user-name-value"
                   type  = "text"
            >

            Password

            <input id    = "password-entry"
                   class = "border-01px-black-solid"
                   name  = "password-value"
                   type  = "password"
            >

            <input id    = "login-button"
                   name  = "login-submit"
                   type  = "submit"
                   value = "Log In"
            >

            <div id = "footer-section">
                <div id = "footer-internal-links">
                    <div id    = "footer-internal-links-box"
                         class = "vertically-centred"
                    >
                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-site-map-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Site Map
                        </span>

                        <div id    = "footer-internal-links-buffer-1"
                             class = "footer-internal-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-privacy-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Privacy
                        </span>

                        <div id    = "footer-internal-links-buffer-2"
                             class = "footer-internal-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <span id    = "footer-internal-links-disclaimer-text"
                              class = "footer-text
                                       footer-internal-links-text"
                        >
                            Disclaimer
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id = "footer-external-links">
                    <div id    = "footer-external-links-box"
                         class = "vertically-centred"
                    >
                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-facebook"
                             alt   = "External Link Facebook"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >

                        <div id    = "footer-external-links-buffer-1"
                             class = "footer-external-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-twitter"
                             alt   = "External Link Twitter"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >

                        <div id    = "footer-external-links-buffer-2"
                             class = "footer-external-links-horizontal-buffer-015px"
                        >
                        </div>

                        <img id    = "footer-external-link-youtube"
                             src   = "Images/Footer%20Facebook%20Symbol%2032%20x%2032.png"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    <?php

    echo $message;
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

RE-EDIT
**Headers Should be set at the starting of your php script** Need Comments

Comment: Thank you Azmat karim - the sample and full versions of my files work just fine after implementing your suggestion of moving the PHP control code to the top of the file.  Two follow up questions, though.  Firstly, is there a particular reason why you changed the error message to using the $message structure?  Secondly, why did my sample code still work if you removed the `Site Map` line?

Comment: 1-I had use message because you don't want to show text at the top of the  page. secondly text outside <html> tag will be not valid with  [w3c] (https://validator.w3.org/) standards.

2- its bizarre really dont know reason. well you can try using tag <span> for the text Site Map, privacy and Disclaimer and try maybe that work. and let me know if that works